# Blocking query on a given foreign key until all inserts for that foreign key complete

Tags: mysql, insert, locking, foreign-keys

I have two workers that do concurrent insert/select on a relatively large (circa 60 million rows) MySQL table.

1. Worker 1 inserts a new row and enqueues a message that includes the new row's foreign key. This occurs roughly once every day for a given foreign key value.
2. Worker 2 dequeues the message, queries the most recent record for the foreign key in the table and processes it further.

It seems that, more often than not, Worker 2 does not get the latest record from the table. Is there a way to block Worker 2's queries for a given foreign key until the insert on that foreign key has completed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably lack of some key information in order to answer precisely, but...

... my *guess* is that the "message" arrive before the changes made to the DB in one transaction are visible of the other one.

Please remember that depending on your transaction isolation level (1) the changes are not propagated to the DB *before* you successfully committed the transaction. And (2) the new state of the DB is not visible until you start a *new* transaction.

And even so, as far as I know, MySQL does not guarantee any "propagation delay". And I don't think there is any mechanism available in MySQL to signal other connections than a transaction has successfully committed and that changes are now visible.

---

I don't know your system, but just as an advice, I don't think that using a message queue to signal a change *but* using MySQL to store the actual change data is a good solution. If I were you, I would take a look at a proper messaging system such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), that not only will allow to signal a change, but will also carry the new state -- with almost, if not all, the same guarantees as a RDBMS. Maybe you could refactor your application in order to use a messaging queue to *process* changes, and only once done, use MySQL to permanently *store* data.